# Advanced Custom Fields not showing in Custom Post Types UI

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

Asking here because of better response rate than Wordpess community.

I set up a custom post type called Training Services. I created a custom field called content_snippet and assigned it to only apply to the relevant post type. I see the field on the post type edit screen and enter in some lorem ipsum.

My code for implementation is below (content-page.php): Why does the title, content and thumbnail of the post type show on the front-end but not the custom field? It simply shows an empty tag where the lorem should be if I look at it in chrome dev tools.

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
<!-- Custom Fields
================================================== -->
<?php
$content_snippet    = get_field('content_snippet');
?>

<section class="container-fluid section-spacing" style="border:1px solid black;">
    <div class="  text-align-center row" style="border:1px solid green;">

        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <hr class="headingUnderline">
        <div class="responsiveShrink" style="border:1px solid yellow;"><?php the_content() ; ?></div>

        <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'training_services', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC' ) ); ?>

        <?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="text-align-center col-xs-12 col-sm-6" style="border:1px solid red;">
            <div class="postWrapper">


                <div class="imageWrapper">

                    <?php
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        the_post_thumbnail();
                    }
                ?>

                </div>
                <div class="postContentWrapper">


                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <div><?php echo $content_snippet; ?></div>
                    <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>

                </div>



            </div>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Stupid mistake. Custom field must be declared inside the loop. Leaving this up for future readers.